# SCSS. Reference second level ascending selector

Tags: css, sass

One of the techniques to organise classes in the scope of avoiding collisions, is to extend a parent's class + add some suffix. For example:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="a__b">
  <div class="a__c">
    <span class="a__d">
```

From considerations of not duplicating code, in sass/scss files, one can refer a parent with the help of an ampersand - `&`, so above structure can be achieved like this:

```
.a{
 &__b{}
 &__c{}
 &__d{}
```

Which is transfomed into:

```
.a__b {}
.a__c {}
.a__d {}
```

But difficulties appear when one needs to get such a `css` as the result:

```
.a:hover{
  color: red;  
}
.a:hover .a__b{
  color: blue;
}
```

Since the main idea is not to duplicate selectors, a question appears - is there a way to reference second level parent? I know that `&&` ins't an issue but is there a way to simulate double ampersand behaviour?

```
.a{
    &:hover{
        color: red;
        & __b { /* & -> .a:hover, but I need just .a */
            color: blue;
        }
    }

}
```

**Not an issue**, `.a` is duplicated:

```
.a:hover { //here
  color: red;
  .a__b { //here
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

**Also not an issue**:

```
.a { //ok
  &:hover {
  color: red;

    .a__b { //oops, duplicated selector
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

So, from the considerations of avoiding collisions many times classes have long names. And that is when duplicated selectors make code look scary. Imagine, that instead of `.a` selector there would be: `.custom-layers-list-panel-conatiner`. Another reason of avoiding duplicated classes is that if parent class is changed, it should be changed everywhere. Yes, nowadays it's quite trivial task with some specific tools, but it's still remains a place where mistakes can appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** better than Original

```scss
.a{
  $grandparent: &;

  &:hover{
    color: red;

    & #{$grandparent}__b {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

and 
**Original:**

```
@function r-pseudo($s) {
  $string: nth(nth($s, 1), 1);
    @return str-slice($string, 0, str-index($string, ':') - 1);
}

.a{
  &:hover{
    color: red;

    & #{r-pseudo(&)}__b {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

both generate

```
.a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.a:hover .a__b {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks.

Comment: That's awesome! It's a pity that I can't accept and upvote your answer twice :)

Comment: Very ingenious. My upvote and I wear out my hat to @A_Singh :)

Comment: Brilliant. (Your answer should omit the `&` in front of `#{$grandparent}` though for OP's intended result.)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was right, but you've to put the a:hover to the top-level to get the result you wanted. It is nothing what you wanted, but the only way that SCSS will give you your target-result.

I think you looking for this:

```
.a:hover {
  color: red;
  .a__b {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Second try, like this?

```
.a {
  &:hover {
  color: red;

    .a__b {
      color: blue;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. I want to expand this `&:hover` expression.

Comment: Like the second try? (I don't/can't follow which parent you want to select and why. Do you've an example?)

Comment: Thank but still no :) The main idea is to get rid of such a construction,   since in the original code there is a class like: `.custom-layers-list-panel` instead of a, and I don't want to duplicate it. It looks ugly.

Comment: So you want to add an define `:hover` to all tags which are using the `.a__b`-class?

Comment: In my post there is css what i expect to get, but I don't want to use `.a` selector more than once in my sass. Neither i want to use `.a__b` selector.

Comment: I don't understand how you would to select your target then, if you don't declare which one you want. I mean you could use `*`, but without conditions this would apply to every element. (and wouldn't be that, was you're trying to do. Or are we talking about something like a mixin, that you want to include on different tags, id's and class's?

Comment: thank you very much for paying attention for my issue. I've updated my post, hope it became more clearer.